# SwiftMail generated email shows text/plain part in multipart email rather than text/html in gmail

Tags: php, email, gmail, swiftmailer

I'm using the following to generate a SwiftMail message (excuse the wrappers)

```
$message = $mailHelper->createMessage(); // This is an instance of Swift_Message
$message->setTo($addresses)
        ->setFrom([$template->getEmail() => $template->getName()])
        ->setSubject($template->getSubject())
        ->setBody($template->getTextContent($twig, $replacements), 'text/plain');
$message->addPart($template->getHtmlContent($twig, $replacements), 'text/html');

$mailHelper->sendMessage($message)
```

I receive the message ok, but in gmail it shows me the text version. All the encoding looks correct to me.

```
Return-Path: <[email]>
Received: from [127.0.0.1] (ec2-54-149-246-93.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com. [54.149.246.93])
        by smtp.gmail.com with ESMTPSA id kv7sm1686300pab.20.2015.09.10.09.11.03
        for <[email]>
(version=TLSv1 cipher=ECDHE-RSA-RC4-SHA bits=128/128);
        Thu, 10 Sep 2015 09:11:04 -0700 (PDT)
Message-ID: <bf6b3e989767a5cab5ebf8ddbfc27040@swift.generated>
Date: Thu, 10 Sep 2015 16:11:03 +0000
Subject: Welcome to [App]
From: [Company] <[email]>
To: "[email]" <[email]>
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/alternative;
 boundary="_=_swift_v4_1441901463_d2266ae39e8919de6200347d60861abb_=_"


 --_=_swift_v4_1441901463_d2266ae39e8919de6200347d60861abb_=_
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable

[url]

--_=_swift_v4_1441901463_d2266ae39e8919de6200347d60861abb_=_
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable

<a href=3D"app://[url]">[url]</a>

--_=_swift_v4_1441901463_d2266ae39e8919de6200347d60861abb_=_--
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it turns out there were two mistakes.

1) Using a custom schema in the href (which I removed from the example above because I considered it sensitive). I guess gmail considers the schema dangerous and then strips the anchor. This is actually a good thing.

2) I was in fact seeing the content from the html version, it's just the only thing that was left was the url, which is what was in the text version too.

**TL;DR:** Don't use a custom schema for your mobile app in emails. Route it through a browser first.